# Javascript code mysteriously not working

Tags: scripting

I tried to improve a web page that was working and make it be a sort of slide show, alternating between the three resorts.   The pictures and everything should be valid.  Doesn't seem to matter if I put the script in the header or in the body, it doesn't seem to be operating either way.

What is even stranger is that if I put an end script tag after the alert, then make a new script tag, then the alert is called.  As it is right now though, not even the alert is being called, though I'm not sure why, as  I also commented out pretty much all the scripting code, trying to find the problem area, and it's still not working.   I'm baffled.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> The Resorts </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./main.css">





</head>
<body>



<div id="content">
<div id="logo">
<img src="./logo.png"></img>
</div>
<div id="container">
<nav id="hor">
<div><a href="home.html"> Home </a> </div>
<div><a href="mountains.html"> The Mountains </a></div>
<div><a href="resorts.html"> The Resorts </a></div>
<div><a href="snowreports.html"> Snow Reports </a></div>
<div><a href="eventsandactivities.html"> Events &amp Activities </a></div>
<div><a href="plantrip.html"> Plan A Trip </a></div>
</nav>
<div id="middle">
<nav id="vert">
<a href="home.html"> Home </a> <br/>
<a href="mountains.html"> The Mountains </a><br/>
<a href="resorts.html"> The Resorts </a><br/>
<a href="snowreports.html"> Snow Reports </a><br/>
<a href="eventsandactivities.html"> Events &amp Activities </a><br/>
<a href="plantrip.html"> Plan A Trip </a>
</nav>

<div id="text-container">
Bla bla bla
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="footercontainer">
<footer>
&copy;  2016   

</footer>
</div>
</div>

<script>


window.alert("Houston, we have a problem.");

var count = 1;



<!--

var changing = setInterval(moveImage, 6000);




function moveImage()
{




increaseCount();

}

function increaseCount()
{
count++;


if (count > 3)
count = 1;

changeImage();

}

function changeImage()
{


var tc = document.getElementById("text-container");

if (count == 1)
{
tc.innerHTML = "
<h1>   The Resorts </h1>" + 
"<h2> The West Resort </h2>" + 
"<figure><img src='./image1.jpg' alt='West Resort' width=300; height=225;></img><figcaption><B> The West Resort</B></figcaption></figure>"+
"<p> The West Resort has everything from wide-open beginner areas to challenging terrain parks to gladed tree skiing hideaways. It has a young, energetic feel, but there's more to it than just jumps and jibs. 

West is home to the Children's Sports Center, the Bullwheel Bar and Grill and the Foggy Goggle where fashion shows, movie premieres and live performances are held on a regular basis.  </p>";
}

else if (count == 2)
{
tc.innerHTML = "
<h1>   The Resorts </h1>" + 
"<h2> The East Resort </h2>" + 
"<figure><img src='./image4.jpg' alt='East Resort' width=300; height=225;></img><figcaption><B> The East Resort</B></figcaption></figure>"+
"<p> The East Resort boasts the longest trails in the region serviced by a single high-speed quad. Its long, groomed, cruising trails make it perfect for carving, but it is also home to the Olympic Bowl, the 

longest, steepest bump run in the region. After a quick ascent on the Diamond Peaks Express, you'll find an additional 20 acres of beginner terrain up top. With 1,600 vertical feet of uninterrupted corduroy, the 

East Resort offers traditional skiers and snowboarders a true alpine experience without having to journey far from home.   </p>";

}

else
{

tc.innerHTML = "
<h1>   The Resorts </h1>" + 
"<h2> The North Resort </h2>" + 
"<figure><img src='./image9.jpg' alt='North Resort' width=300; height=225;></img><figcaption><B> The North Resort</B></figcaption></figure>"+
"<p> The North Resort is the perfect family-friendly ski resort with 70 acres of gently rolling terrain and historic, log cabins that are terrific for exploring. It is big enough to offer a true winter experience but 

small enough to maintain its historical warmth and charm. Spend the afternoon shushing down the slopes or warm up by the fireplace with a cup of hot chocolate at the North Lodge. It is one of the region’s 

oldest base lodges with ties that go back to the Big Pines ski clubs of the 1940s.    </p>";

}

}
-->

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

However, this code, which I've based the one above on, IS working, and I don't see what I'm doing differently enough for it to suddenly stop working.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Carousel </title>



</head>
<body>


<div style="border: 1px solid black;  width = 190; height = 300;>
<div style ="border: 1px solid black; " id="imageStuff">

<figure><img src="./mongoose image.jpg" width=190; height =100;></img>
<figcaption><B> Mongoose </B></figcaption>
</figure>
</div>


<div style="border: 1px solid black;  background-color: blue;" width= 190; height=100;>





<button onClick="decreaseCount()"><</button>
<button onClick="changeCount(1)">1</button>
<button onClick="changeCount(2)">2</button>
<button onClick="changeCount(3)">3</button>
<button onClick="changeCount(4)">4</button>
<button onClick="changeCount(5)">5</button>
<button onClick="increaseCount()">></button>
</div>

</div>
<script>

var count = 1;
var images= [ "./mongoose image.jpg", "./fossa.jpg", "./ferret.png", "./civet.jpg", "./hyrax.jpg"];
var labels =["Mongoose", "Fossa", "Ferret", "Civet", "Hyrax"];

var changing = setInterval(moveImage, 3000);

function increaseCount()
{
changeCount(count+1)
}

function decreaseCount()
{
changeCount(count-1);
}


function moveImage()
{




increaseCount();

}

function changeCount(count2)
{
count = count2;

if (count < 1)
count = 5;

if (count > 5)
count = 1;

changeImage();

}

function changeImage()
{





document.getElementById("imageStuff").innerHTML = "<figure><img src='" + images[count-1] + "'  width=190 height = 100;></img>" +
"<figcaption><B>" + labels[count-1] + "</B></figcaption></figure>";





}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, but it is commented out.   That shouldn't matter to my issue with the 1st document.

Comment: There, the php code, which was never an issue anyway, is gone.   I'm not sure why the script thing in the first document isn't working.  I've commented out practically everything to try and find the problem area.  Even so, the problem still persists.   And I know my computer can find JS as if I just had the alert only, it WOULD work.

Comment: I thought I tried it in a document ready thing with JQuery and it still didn't work.

Comment: Also, the 2nd document didn't have it in an onload thing either and it still worked.

Comment: There is one difference between the two, : the first one has a CSS import and the 2nd doesn't, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: As you can see, this one by W3 Schools wasn't in an onload and it's working fine:   http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_setinterval2

Comment: Did remove the alert, no change.  As for the script thing, since javascript is the default one, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Weird, I removed the code in the in the last function and put in an alert and now it's working.  So now I have a closer guess on the problem area.

Comment: Final suggestion, move the ending script tag just after the alert statement and move it down line by line to find the error.